# bash - change value in array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a problem with change value in array.
I have several arrays: tab1, tab2.... etc. 
I want to change some value in these arrays using two variable:

```
x=2
y=3
tab$y[$x]="#"
```

it doesn't work.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is your friend:

```
eval tab$y[$x]="#"
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `declare`, it's safer than `eval`:

```
declare tab$y[$x]="#"
```

Comment: Yes, and I didn't know this one works. Just for completion, is there an equally elegant way to get the value of `${tab$y[$x]}`?

Comment: @ChenLevy: Not that I can think of, but there are [probably better alternatives](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) to this kind of thing anyway.